# The prop is lost after the page is refreshed in react

Tags: reactjs

The prop is lost after the page is refreshed in react,
I have a page which lists the shop details like name & location. There is a link for each listed shop when clicked that shop details will be opened..So i have passed the name through the link  . Which I can acces by props.location.state. but when I refresh the page the name is lost.

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/listShops/' + shop.id,  state: shop.name } } >
```

when I am on the listShops page I get the state at the first time but if the page is refreshed the prop is lost.

Comment: Hey Time, could you explain a bit more your problem? What is `listShops`? Which state are you talking about? How did you implement Link?

Comment: The state of your app doesn't persist anyway, unless you hard code your initial state, otherwise you have to use somthing like localStorage to get your state persist after a page reload

Answer (score 0):

> I get the state at the first time but if the page is refreshed the prop is lost.

You most likely have an internal state that is based off a prop and are not updating it (the state) when the prop is changed by the parent component.

You can use [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) to accomplish that

```
componentWillReceive (nextProps) {

  // update your internal state that depends on the props
  // const internalState = nextProps.something
  // this.setState({internalState}
}
```

Comment: Please, pay attention that "Props" is missing at the end. It should be: componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)..

Comment: And I also got Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed. Use getDerivedStateFromProps instead.